# What are the special properties of adjunctions that generate polynomial monads

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

The subject of [polynomial monads](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4931.pdf) is well trodden.  We know that every monad is generated by an adjunction.  What are the special properties of any adjunction that generates a polynomial monad?

Take a domain, $D$, like the interval domain, and look at the set of maps $F = [D,D]$, where $f \in F,  f: D \rightarrow D$.  Let $F_a \subset F$ be the subset of all $f$ that preserve both meet and join, so they form adjunctions when $D$ is considered a category.  Is there a subset $P \subset F_a$ which generate polynomial monads?  What are the special properties of such $f' \in P$

Comment: Certainly if the left and right adjoints are polynomial, then the induced monad will be polynomial, and this would seem the natural condition to impose. One would hope that the Kleisli and Eilenberg–Moore adjunction for a polynomial monad to comprise polynomial functors, though I'm not sure whether or not this is true.